# What dependency strategy suits this small app

Tags: oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have a small PHP **command line** application that I am creating in order to learn some common design patterns and oop techniques.

I have set up all of my relevant classes so that they are not instantiating objects internally, but instead they are being given their objects they require via their constructor.

The problem now is how do I orchestrate everything so that each object gets the dependencies it requires.  I have read about dependency injection containers and frameworks but this seems overkill for a small command line app + I am having a hard time understanding how they would fit into my application.

Currently the flow goes like this:

- Program is executed by user at the command line
- Bootstrap occurs, i.e. autoloader etc instantiated etc
- I have a factory method that sets up the dependencies (all hard coded inside the class) and returns an application object.  There around 2 dependencies for the main application and each of those has a further 2 dependencies each (this is the tricky part i think)
- Application->run() is called.

What would be the best approach in terms of a balance between flexibility and simplicity as I dont believe the design (around the factory) is quite correct.

Comment: Maybe you can get some ideas from this link: http://fabien.potencier.org/article/50/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-1

Comment: The factory approach is correct. At the end of the day, something has to do the job of instantiating objects and setting up the relationships between them. The thing that does this is the Factory.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it your application is organised fairly well, construction is separate from the application logic and your dependencies are managed clearly.

You could of course add configurable dependencies or utilise a dependency injection frameworks, however, I would recommend avoiding both of these unless the application requires it. If you do start using a DI framework, make sure you keep everything cohesive even though you are using this magic tool and try and move everything away from the framework when it is possible (i.e. Having modules handle the internal dependencies through factories rather than rely on the framework). Split functionality into modules when it makes sense.

I am working on improvements to a large nebulous application that runs all of its dependencies through a DI framework and it is slow to start up and turns into a bit of a sack-o-crap and is not pleasant to work with, it is an application that does "everything" rather than delegate tasks onto modules and libraries and has zero unit tests.

The main thing to note is that there are a lot of solutions to every problem and learning different patterns is a great idea, there are many types of factory pattern, learn them all. Some are simple, some are more sophisticated, you will get a feeling for what works in different situations.

My personal recommendation, if your application works as you intend, it is organised as it sounds like it is, and if you haven't already (and the aim of the game is to improve your techniques), practice:

- Documenting (write some documentation and throw it at a dev friend to see how they deal with it)
- Testing (write some unit tests and then rewrite the application a different way)
- Benchmarking (run profiling on your code and try to find ways to optimize it)

Try a different approach to factory loading, dynamic factory, builder pattern, framework, use the benchmarks to understand what you traded off.

Answer (score 0):

Your application should work like this:

```
$app = new Application($arg1, $arg2);
$app->run();
```

All other classes should be instantiated in the `Application`, and passed as parameters to constructors of other classes. Rule of thumb is: any constructor should have **less than 3 arguments**. If you follow this rule everything will be fine.